# Bounded sets in locally convex topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a (Hausdorff) locally convex topological vector space, and assume that the topology $\tau$ is by a family of seminorms $(\rho_{i})_{i\in I}$. Also, we assume that this family of semnorms is saturated: $\max\{\rho_{i},\rho_{j}\}$ is also a semninorm for every $i,j\in I$.

It is known that a (non-empty) set $B\subset X$ is bounded if (and only if) $\rho_{i}(B)<\infty$ for every $i\in I$.

My question is the following: There is such $(X,\tau)$ and $(\rho_{i})_{i\in I}$ such that $\sup\{\rho_{i}(B):i\in  I\}=\infty$ for some bounded $B\subset X$? If $X$ is metrizable (i.e., the family of seminorms is almost countable), the answer is "no". But, What happens in the general case?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Even if metrisable. Let $X = \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$, $\rho_i(x) = \max \{ \lvert x_k\rvert : k \leqslant i\}$, $$B = \{ x : \rho_i(x) \leqslant i\}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice example!